# User Registration - Validation & Storing

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have started to write the validation for user registration. This form is so users can register on the site, however I'm having issues with how to properly write validation for each field.

so far:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="ic"></div>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="grid_12">
                        <h2 class="h-pad1">Open an Account with Us</h2>
                        <form action="" id="validate" class="form" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="login">Username:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="text" name="username" class="validate[required]" id="username" maxlength="15"/></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="password" name="password" class="validate[required]" id="pass" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Repeat Password:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="password" name="rpassword" class="validate[required]" id="rpass" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="formRow">
                    <label for="pass">Email:</label>
                    <div class="loginInput"><input type="text" name="email" class="validate[required]" id="email" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
```

What would be the proper code to add? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your most important task is to learn how to use [document.getElementById()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) if your  going to be using regular javascript. With that function you can grab the value in the different fields and check what is stored in them.

I would have a highlevel function **validateRegistrationForm()** that calls functions for validating each field. For example

```
function validateRegistrationForm(){
     if(!validateEmailField()) // Invalid email format
          return;
     if(!validatePasswordField()) // Invalid password length
          return;
     if(validateUserNameField()) // invalide characters in email
          return;
     .
     .
    etc.
}

function validateEmailField(){
    var x=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
        errorPopup("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    if(email==x) //If the old email is equal to the current then perform no check for uniqueness. On the server side the email portion will be ignored.
        return true;

    return isEmailUnique(); // return true if the email is unique
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like:

```
function validate()
{

var uName = document.getElementById('username');

if(uName == '' or uName=' ')
{

 // do something

}

repeat for other elements.

.
.
.
.

// in the end, you can return true; if all validation condition meet or else return false;

}
```